# User list bulk upload option for Enterprise applicaiton

Tags: forms, users, uploading

I am working on Enterprise online application.  Rather than adding user information by using conventional form filling concept, client has asked us to provide bulk user list upload option in which admin user can add 'n' number of users in a single shot.  The issue is, some fields are mandatory and some of them or not.  While uploading user details as excel, csv format, how can validate them as conventional form fields does?  I understand that would be better to provide pre-defined template to user in which user can fill-up the respective details and upload them.  After uploading the excel/csv files into the application validation has to be happened on screen.

Let's assume, if any of mandatory fields are missing in the uploaded document, how can we update them rather than updating the same file in local system and upload them again.

If any best practices are available, really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this process

1) When user uploads a file, show him a preview of what he/she has uploaded.

2) Show an waiting indicator like [this image](https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictofoundry-pro-vector-set/512/LoadingIndicator-128.png) at the right side of a row and while that indicator is revolving do a validation of the row.

3) If the row is valid, then show a selected checkbox in the place of that wait-indicator to tell that the user that this row is good to be uploaded.

4) If the row is invalid, then show a red cross mark in place of that wait indicator while clearly highlighting the column that is not a valid input.

5) Finally, put a button at the bottom of that preview page (preferably a sticky footer) that will finally submit those valid rows after which checkboxes are selected.

This interaction will take care of your concerns of communicating invalid records to the user. If your client insists, then add a checkbox with the upload button - 'Show Preview'.

Comment: Ok good solution for my question.  When I am coming to your 4th point where you have mentioned about invalid details row, how can I make correction on screen with simple interaction?  By that time I wont like to update the excel sheet and upload them again.  That will be huge irritation to the user who is handling this process... Any solution for that?  I am worrying about worst case scenario than the happy path.

Comment: @Vasethvan fair point. You can given an option to the user to download 'Invalidated' data in excel again so that they can fill it up and upload again. I am assuming that your website doesn't have the edit user functionality built in, so excel/csv upload is the only way.

Comment: Ok here is my opinion in that case.  When you find an invalid data let's say if you haven't entered Gender info, clicking on invalid row preview, that can be shown as drop down list with required list.  There I can choose the correct value and make the row as valid one.  I am not sure about the technical feasibility.  But defiantly there is way to handle it.

Comment: @Vasethvan I don't know about your tech stack, but this one can definitely be done and shouldn't require too many changes in your app as well.

Comment: @gurvinder327 Thanks for your quick responses.  Really appreciated.